# Run automated tests on a schedule to server as health check

Tags: testing, selenium, build, integration

I was tasked with creating a health check for our production site. It is a .NET MVC web application. There are a lot of dependencies and therefore points of failure e.g. a document repository, Java Web services, Site Minder policy server etc.

Management wants us to be the first to know if ever any point fails. Currently we are playing catch up if a problem arises, because it is the the client that informs us. I have written a suite of simple Selenium WebDriver based integration tests that test the sign in and a few light  operations e.g. retrieving documents via the document api. I am happy with the result but need to be able to run them on a loop and notify IT when any fails.

We have a TFS build server but I'm not sure if it is the right tool for the job. I don't want to continuously build the tests, just run them. Also it looks like I can't define a build schedule more frequently than on a daily basis.

I would appreciate any ideas on how best achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a _very_ broad question! To get an idea of just how broad, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems

Comment: have you looked into cron or scheduled task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called a suite of "Smoke Tests".  Smoke Tests are basically very short and sweet, independent tests that test various pieces of the app to make sure it's production ready, just as you say.

I am unfamiliar with TFS, but I'm sure the information I can provide you will be useful, and transferrable.

When you say "I don't want to build the tests, just run them."  Any CI that you use, **NEEDS** to build them TO run them.  Basically "building" will equate to "compiling".  In order for your CI to actually run the tests, it needs to compile.

As far as running them, If the TFS build system has any use whatsoever, it will have a periodic build option.  In Jenkins, I can specify a Cron time to run.  For example:

```
0 0 * * *
```

means "run at 00:00 every day (midnight)"

or,

```
30 5 * 1-5 *
```

which means, "run at 5:30 every week day"

Since you are making Smoke Tests, it's important to remember to keep them **short and sweet**.  Smoke tests should test one thing at a time. for example:

```
testLogin()
testLogout()
testAddSomething()
testRemoveSomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

A web application health check is a very important feature. The use of smoke tests can be very useful in working out if your website is running or not and these can be automated to run at intervals to give you a notification that there is something wrong with your site, preferable before the customer notices.

However where smoke tests fail is that they only tell you that the website does not work, it does not tell you why. That is because you are making external calls as the client would, you cannot see the internals of the application. I.E is it the database that is down, is a network issue, disk space, a remote endpoint is not functioning correctly.

Now some of these things should be identifiable from other monitoring and you should definitely have an error log but sometimes you want to hear it from the horses mouth and the best thing that can tell you how you application is behaving is your application itself. That is why a number of applications have a baked in health check that can be called on demand.

## Health Check as a Service

The health check services I have implemented in the past are all very similar and they do the following:

1. Expose an endpoint that can be called on demand, i.e /api/healthcheck. Normally this is private and is not accessible externally.
2. It returns a Json response containing:

   - the overall state
   - the host that returned the result (if behind a load balancer)
   - The application version
   - A set of sub system states (these will indicate which component is not performing)
3. The service should be resilient, any exception thrown whilst checking should still end with a health check result being returned.
4. Some sort of aggregate that can present a number of health check endpoints into one view

## Here is one I made earlier

After doing this a number of times I have started a library to take out the main wire up of the health check and exposing it as a service. Feel free to use as an example or use the nuget packages.

https://github.com/bronumski/HealthNet

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/HealthNet.WebApi
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/HealthNet.Owin
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/HealthNet.Nancy